# Solved: getActivity() in SharedPreference declaration in Fragment returns Exception

Tags: android

[EDIT at the end (self solved)]

I am trying to access a SharedPreference file inside a tab fragment.
Until now, the declaration of the Shared preference worked perfectly.
Today I added some stuff non related and when trying to launch app I recieve this exception:

```
2019-09-15 17:39:16.178 26501-26501/com.example.calculmoyennesv2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main
    Process: com.example.calculmoyennesv2, PID: 26501
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment NotesFragment{f4159ad} not attached to a context.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:696)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:760)
    at com.example.calculmoyennesv2.NotesFragment.<init>(NotesFragment.java:38)
    at com.example.calculmoyennesv2.ui.main.SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(SectionsPagerAdapter.java:36)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:105)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:992)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3301)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2028)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2330)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8511)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

I found out that the exception comes from this line:

```
private SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.mSharedPref), MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It seems that the `getActivity()` throws an exception, as the log tells me that the fragment isn't attached to a context, but I don't really understand why

Full code of the fragment :

```
package com.example.calculmoyennesv2;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.calculmoyennesv2.adapters.ItemListViewAdapter;
import com.example.calculmoyennesv2.models.ItemListViewModel1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NotesFragment extends Fragment {


    public NotesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    private String[] title_array, subtitle_array;
    private SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.mSharedPref), MODE_PRIVATE); 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); 

        List<ItemListViewModel1> list = listfiller();

        ListView testListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.idListViewNotes);
        testListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
               view.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewNomNote)).getText().toString());

                editor.putString(((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewNomNote)).getText().toString(), ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idTextViexNote)).getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
               
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewNomNote)).getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        testListView.setAdapter(new ItemListViewAdapter(getContext(),list));


        return rootView;
    }
    

   private List<ItemListViewModel1> listfiller ()
    {

        title_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.S1_1A_title_array);            subtitle_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.S1_1A_subtitle_array);

        List<ItemListViewModel1> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i< title_array.length; i++)
        {
            list.add(new ItemListViewModel1(title_array[i], subtitle_array[i], preferences.getString(title_array[i],"null")));
        }


        return list;
    }
}
```

[EDIT] I found out the problem, I tried to use the context via `getActivity()` before the `OnCreateView`, I probably made a copy paste of my own code in the wrong area which resulted in me trying to access something not existing yet.

Comment: Please add the answer in the designated area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem, I tried to use the context via `getActivity()` before the `OnCreateView`, I probably made a copy paste of my own code in the wrong area which resulted in me trying to access something not existing yet.